# How to pick a gradient color for a canvas render of a usage bar?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, canvas

I'm attempting to color the usage bar in my Google Chrome extension using capabilities of the HTML5 canvas. The bar itself is a simple DIV:

```
<div id="idUsgBar"></div>
```

with this CSS:

```
#idUsgBar{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: -webkit-canvas(bkgfill);
}
```

So the work is done in JS:

```
//'perc' = percent value from [0 to 100]
//'w' = width of the bar for 100%
//'h' = height of the bar

var w_f = w * perc / 100;

var ctx = document.getCSSCanvasContext("2d", "bkgfill", w, h);
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);

//The issue is calculating r, g, b components for the fill based on 'perc'???
ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(" + r + "," + g + "," + b + ")";

ctx.fillRect(0, 0, w_f, h);
```

So I created a gradient in Photoshop that looks like this, but my thinking that I can simply set the `R` component proportional to the value of `perc` was totally off. This diagram will show what I mean:

[image]

So what is the way to do it?

Comment: 1) You don't define a gradient here (with createLinearRadiant), but you just use a solid fill, so no wonder why the color is uniform. 2) You might want to use hsl colors, easier to handle.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this by doing the following:

1. Create a one-pixel high PNG in the Photoshop with the desired gradient/color pattern. (Called "source of colors" in my sample above.)
2. Add it to the page as an invisible `<img>` with its CSS style set to `display: none;`.
3. Then to get a color for the "usage bar" for a percent value, simply sample it from that `<img>` using `canvas`. For that first load it with [drawImage](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_drawimage.asp)() and then get the pixel's RGB components with [getImageData](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_getimagedata.asp)().

PS. To speed things up I cached all required pixels from the `<img>` in the global array when the page loads, so I can then simply use it later to retrieve RGB values when drawing my "usage bar".